# Probability of getting at most 2 hearts in a 5 card hand, using a normal 52 cards deck?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

I think I know how to do it, but I am not 100% sure and also maybe there is a better way of doing it.

My solution

$$\binom{13}{0} \times \space \binom{39}{5} + \binom{13}{1} \times \space \binom{39}{4} + \binom{13}{2} \times \space \binom{39}{3}$$

Comment: Your method is correct, but you still need to divide by the total number of possible hands.

Comment: Quite.  The "solution" you wrote was the *count* of the number of ways of getting at most two hearts in a five card hand, not the *probability* of doing so.  You still need to divide by $\binom{52}{5}$

Comment: Exactly what @JMoravitz said. You just need to divide it now by the total possible number of 5 card hands.